# How to do Terminal.app Star Wars ASCII?

Tags: terminal, bash

I tried telnet `towel.blinkenlights.nl` and it said `telnet: command not found`. Is it deprecated? It is a bit trivial, but I thought it was worth asking about at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, telnet is deprecated and is not included in High Sierra. If you want it, you’ll have to install it yourself, e.g. using Homebrew. See [here](https://dor.ky/restore-telnet-in-mac-os-high-sierra-10-13/) for more details.